# Google colab drive space decreasing even I save data on google drive

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm quite new to colab. I run my notebook for few hours. I mounted the google drive and I upload data directly there, but the colab disk space is decreasing even though I am not saving anything there, I move it to google drive where I have much bigger space. Does anyone know why is the disk space filling up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colab gives you the illusion of having your Google Drive mounted to it as a filesystem. But behind the scenes, it is really a remote disk that is mounted as a virtual filesystem.

So, when you upload the data through your Colab instance, it first gets uploaded to Colab. Then it starts transferring the data to Drive. This causes the Colab space to be used, until the data is completely uploaded to the Drive. Also, Colab might take some time to refelct the changes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Needed a explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://one.google.com/storage/management - there is an option to permanently delete files from Trash folder on your drive. In my case, these were files that I didn't see in my Trash folder (I already removed the files and emptied the Trash, but apparently the script created some files that were hidden). It worked for me, cleared 13GB.